# show The Google Places API results on map

Tags: google-places-api

I need to place an address on Google map
and show show amenities around it by user request
im new with google map, i read The Google Places API but the only thing it gives me is the detail of the locations in XML or JSON format but it doesnt tel me how to place the locations on the actual map

any help really appriciated
thanks

Comment: Have you also looked at the [Google Maps API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/)?

Comment: Yes i didthats where i found how to get report JSON or XML but i couldnt find how to place the report on the map

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to use the Places API webservice, but instead why don't you use the [Places Library of the JavaScript Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places). There's plenty of documentation and samples there on how to put them on a map.

Comment: thank you that solved the problem
now i have a map which shows the places (like bakery, cafe, etc.) around my default location, the question is that all the searched locations have Detail Balloon (or Marker) but my default location
i was wondering how can i add the balloon to my default location?
here is my code and i need the (contentString) to be my detail balloon for my default location
any help really appreciated

http://www.grandpalacecondominiums.ca/Includefiles/map/place-search_New.htm

Comment: You just need to add a marker with an infowindow: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows If you're having trouble with that, you should start a new question.